# How to click on the svg based Delete icon using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I got  web application, i can login and see a table of transactions. There is icon, i am trying to use webdriver to retrieve icon, i fail to get the icon.

how to click the delete icon and action triggers?

```java
String baseURL = "http://testingapp.workspez.com/login";
driver.get(baseURL);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_email']")).sendKeys("rahul@workspez.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_password']")).sendKeys("Sujeet@19");
driver.findElement(By.className("MuiButton-label")).click();

WebElement generalInfo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='General Info']"));
generalInfo.click();

WebElement md = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Contacts']"));
md.click();

WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input']"));
searchbox.sendKeys("fat1");

WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']"));
search.click();

List<WebElement> menulist = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']"));
System.out.println(menulist.size());
menulist.get(3).click(); 

WebElement deleteicon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='MuiList-root MuiMenu-list MuiList-padding']"));
deleteicon.click();
```

[image]

Comment: `fat1` data have been deleted :) search result fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) enabled `Delete` icon you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
import java.util.Collections;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ElementToBeClickable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\\\WebDrivers\\\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://testingapp.workspez.com/login");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_email']"))).sendKeys("rahul@workspez.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_password']")).sendKeys("Sujeet@19");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'Log In')]")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'General Info')]"))).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input']"))).sendKeys("aa");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root' and @title='Search']")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body']//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']/span[@class='MuiIconButton-label']"))).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button']/*[name()='svg']"))).click();
    }
}
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: svg_delete]